How to exclude Firebase Configuration for a particular flavor in Flutter
I have build a flutter app with 4 flavors : mock, dev, uat and prod.
I have integrated 3 different firebase project to the flavor dev, uat and prod.
If I run those flavor, it is working fine.
I have not and do not want to integrate firebase for the flavor mock.
Now, when I run the flutter app in mock flavor, it is giving me an error like google-services.json is not found, that's obvious as I have not integrated it, but I added the plugin in build.gradle and settings.gradle which is common for other flavor.
I need to find a way to exclude firebase for a particular flavor, both in android and IoS.
Can anyone having any idea on it?
I tried whatever is suggested in this link : Can i disable Firebase plugin for specific flavor?
but it did not work.

Do you have separate main files? How do your run the differente flavors?

"but it did not work" is really hard to help with. If you tried something that you think should work, edit your question to include a minimal repro of that.

Yes @pcba-dev, I do have separate main files, like main_mock.dart, main_dev.dart, main_uat.dart and main_prod.dart

Okay @FrankvanPuffelen, I will add a minimal repo by today EOD.

You could simply use another solution. just add a google-services.json file for the mock flavor too but with dummy values. Only the package name inside the Client-Info section should match the package name for mock flavor.
You dont have to add firebase for that flavor. It is working for me.

This is not a proper solution but yes its a quick workaround. Will wait for some more days then will mark it as correct answer.

I could not find another solution for that so i did this in my own project. It works as expected.
